# Visual Studio Team Services says "Task PowerShell failed" although it didn't

Tags: git, powershell, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm getting the following error at the end of my powershell script in VS Team Services:

> Task PowerShell failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.

However, the script didn't fail. It did everything I wanted it to do. Is there some way I can explain that to VS Team Services?

The script takes the compiled and tested code from VS Team Services and pushes it to a git repository on bitbucket. This way, I can automatically create a docker container from it and update my application. Here is the script:

```
git clone BITBUCKET_URL/example-repo.git
cd example-repo

echo "Clean app-folder and remove Dockerfile"

remove-item app -recurse -force
remove-item Dockerfile -force

new-item -name app -itemtype directory

echo "Copy new files into repository"

cp ../deploy/Dockerfile .
cp ../ExampleApp/bin/Debug/* ./app

echo "Set email, name and include all files"

git config user.email "EMAIL"
git config user.name "NAME"
git add -A

echo "What has changed:"
git status

echo "Commit and Push..."
git commit -m "VS Online Commit"
git push origin master
```

This script runs through and does everything correctly. However, this is the end of my Visual Studio Team Services log:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Powershell: deploy/deploy.ps1
******************************************************************************
Cloning into 'example-repo'...
Clean app-folder and remove Dockerfile
    Directory: C:\PROJECT\example-repo
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----         7/17/2015   7:59 AM            app                                                                       
Copy new files into repository
Set email, name and include all files
What has changed:
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   app/App.exe
    modified:   app/App.pdb
Commit and Push...
 VS Online Commit
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
To BITBUCKET_URL/example-repo.git
b861c96..afd33e6 master -> master
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: PowerShell
******************************************************************************
Task PowerShell failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
******************************************************************************
Finishing Build
******************************************************************************
```

From this output, the following lines were red and similarly like the error line:

```
Cloning into 'example-repo'...
```

and

```
To BITBUCKET_URL/example-repo.git
b861c96..afd33e6 master -> master
```

Could it be that something here returns anything but 0 and that's why VS Team Services "detects" the failure?

How can I prevent that?

**Update:**

Running only `git clone` already shows that there is an error, so it seems like `git clone` and `git push` would really cause something which is treated like an error by VS Team Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Vesper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1627055/vesper) wrote in his answer, git is sending output to stderr and VS Team Services thinks it failed because of that.

However, just redirecting or ignoring stderr doesn't seem like the right solution for me. Instead you can specify:

```
git clone --quiet ...
git push --porcelain ...
```

to stop git from reporting the status on stderr and either stop reporting it at all ([`--quiet`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)) or sending it to stdout ([`--porcelain`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)).

**Update:**

if `git add` is showing warnings about line endings, you can disable it with the following config:

```
git config core.safecrlf false
```

Of course, you might also want to set `core.autocrlf` in the configuration.

Comment: Knowledge of a command's parameters is indeed better than a generalized solution. If it's possible, of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Visual Studio reacts on error channel as if a script did an error. Since your `git` sends some output to error channel, you either use your script with `2>&1` output redirector, or set `$ErrorActionPreference` into `silentlyContinue` in the script, or redirect all `git` command output the same way `2>&1`.

About exit code - if your script does not contain a `exit <code>` command, its exit code is zero, as all `git` commands' exit codes are absorbed by Powershell while it interpretes the script, are available in the script right after each command as `$lastExitCode` but dropped if not used.

Comment: thx for the hint. I didn't manage to use `2>&1` however, I guess that's more of a workaround than the solution I came up with ultimately